# Series about a young man struggling to become king in middle ages setting

Tags: story-identification, novel, medieval

I read a book in the early nineties about a young man who becomes a king in a medieval setting, lots of drama and backstabbing. I can remember that it was part of a series, most likely a trilogy. I can’t even remember if it was fictional Europe or just some unnamed land.  I don’t remember there being any magic or fantasy elements. Also I feel like this book was written in the early 90s as I remembering reading the novel as a brand new book in 91/92. In most of the novel the main protagonist is a young man. Can anyone help?

Although I don't remember it having magic or fantasy elements, it definitely was either alternate history or just an non-Earth world. It's possible that it was a low-magic setting.

Comment: IF this is about 'The Hammer and the Cross' by Harry Harrison it most definitely is fantasy. The time period (1993) and premise both match. It is the first novel of an alternate history trilogy in 9th century Britain.

Comment: @Bookeater Thanks for the suggestion, but reading about H&C the covers didn't look right and the story seemed to be based on conquest, the novel I remember was a reluctant young king just trying to survive, not conquering the world.

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't rather ask this question on [literature.se] SE? Literature also welcomes ID questions, and in fact it has many of the same answering experts as this site. On this question we've currently got one mod flag for potential migration and one for reopening, and no reopen votes yet. Migration would solve the problem of some people thinking this is on-topic here and some people thinking it isn't :-)

Comment: This describes many novels. I originally thought of [Nobody's Son](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobody's_Son) by Sean Stewart (but it's from 1993).

Comment: @Spencer that certainly sounds more like it. I couldn't find anything on the web, is that part of a series or a one and done novel? Thank you by the way for trying.

Comment: I'll just toss in David Eddings. Just read a couple of them, but his series seem to run in this vein. Belgariad, Malloreon, etc. Medieval with a little magic, knights and royals on quests trying to regain their throne, etc.

Comment: I was thinking of Guy Gavriel Kay's *A Song for Arbonne* at first -- a novel published in 1992 -- but the young man who finally becomes a king at the end was a character who only existed onstage in that single novel; he wasn't scheduled to be a major character in an entire trilogy.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is the series beginning with [*The Prince in Waiting*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KU4O1Y2)?

> A thirteen-year-old’s expectations of royalty give way to adventure in
> the first book in the post-apocalyptic Sword of the Spirits trilogy
> from the author of The Tripods series.
>
> In Winchester, roles are clearly defined. Warriors fight battles every
> spring. Dwarfs make the swords and the shields. Grotesque mutants are
> the servant class. Seers interpret the wishes and predictions of the
> spirits. And the Prince is the ruler of the city.
>
> Thirteen-year-old Luke has no reason to suspect that any of this will
> change. It’s been this way for centuries...at least since the year
> 2000.

It was originally printed in about 1970, and reprinted recently, perhaps also in the 90s when you read it?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly one of Katherine Kurtz's Deryni trilogies?  There were several (and some individual books as well).  Many of them deal with the early years of King Kelson's reign.

> young man who becomes a king

Kelson became king in the first book of the first trilogy, *Deryni Rising*, at the age of 14.

> in a medieval setting,

The country is Gwynedd.  King, dukes, earls, barons, fealty, garderobes.  Very medieval. This fictional world roughly parallels 10th, 11th, and 12th century England, Scotland, and Wales.

> lots of drama and backstabbing.

Check.  His father the king is murdered in a way that looks like he had a heart attack.  The new young king has to fight for the throne (including a battle by magic with a sorceress, in the cathedral during his coronation.)  Infighting.  Traitors.

> I can remember that it was part of a series, most likely a trilogy.

The Deryni series is made up of many books (the majority, I believe, published before 1990, though definitely not all).  Within the larger series, there are several sets of trilogies, two of which are about King Kelson as a young man.  The first, when he comes to the throne, consists of *Deryni Rising*, *Deryni Checkmate*, and *High Deryni*.  The second, several years into King Kelson's reign, *The Bishop's Heir*, *The King's Justice*, and *The Quest for Saint Camber*.

> fictional Europe or just some unnamed land.

Gwynedd; fictional land with fictional neighbors, with hints of medieval England and neighbors.

> I don’t remember there being any magic or fantasy elements.

The OP also says, however,

> Although I don't remember it having magic or fantasy elements, it definitely was either alternate history or just an non-Earth world. It's possible that it was a low-magic setting.

Here it is only a partial match.  I don't know whether you can call this a low-magic setting.  However, it could be a match anyway; the magic in this world is not witches or druids or that sort of magic, and 'spells' are only a small part and rarely mentioned.  The Deryni are a subset of humans who have special abilities which include telepathy, telekinesis, and other more 'magical' seeming abilities.  The background 'theme' running through all the books is the issues between the Deryni, who have powers, and the other people, who are the majority, many of whom fear and hate them.

> Also I feel like this book was written in the early 90s as I remembering reading the novel as a brand new book in 91/92.

The first trilogy was published in the 1970's, but was republished every few years until the mid-1980's, with the third book, *High Deryni*, having a reprint (in the UK) in 1990.

The second was published in the mid- to late 1980's, in several reprints.

> In most of the novel the main protagonist is a young man.

Check, Kelson, in the two trilogies I mentioned (there is another series about an earlier era; while there are important characters who are young men, the main protagonist, Camber of Culdi, is an older man).

Comment: I hope this will help someone; the OP has not been seen in a while...